# PHPword, get total number of pages

Tags: phpword

I'm using `PHPword` to create a `docx` file.  I  need a method/function that can  get the total number of pages created.

I know `PHPword` does support pages numbering which is easily done using `$footer->addPreserveText('Page {PAGE} of {NUMPAGES}.');`

once i got the total number of pages, i can create extra pages if the document has less the 20 pages.

Answer (score 2):

I also asked this question. While there isn't a built-in per se, you can get the info by opening the ZIP file manually and looking at the app.xml file within

Check out my answer and code sample here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40228208/6247265

And here's the relevant code:

```
 // Include PHPWord and other stuff before here
  function getPages() {
    $zip = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive();
    $zip->open("/path/to/your/document.docx");
    preg_match("/\<Pages>(.*)\<\/Pages\>/", $zip->getFromName("docProps/app.xml"), $var);
    return $var[0];
  }
```

There's a catch to this: the page numbers will be wrong. I got around this by `exec()`ing to `winword.exe` using the `/m` switch to run the `ToolsWordCountRecount` macro. So something like this:

`c:\path\to\winword.exe /mToolsWordCountRecount /mFileSave /mFileCloseOrExit yourfile.docx`

This forces Word to recount the pages, saves the document then quits. Then you can run `getPages` to correctly count the number of pages in a document.

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, then you should flag it as a duplicate instead of posting a link-dominated answer. Note that it is fine to dupe an older question to a newer one of the newer one has an answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14085480)

Comment: @EJoshuaS You're right. I figured being a SO question with edit history, it'd be fine. I've updated my answer with code and an extra tidbit about forcing Word to recount pages

Answer (score 0):

The {PAGE} and {NUMPAGES} are specific word field codes that are processed by Word instead than phpword, i.e. phpword doesn't actually know the page number values, it just passes these field codes as they are into the resulting word document.

As an answer to the original question, I don't think that you can get the number of pages information from phpword.

[more information about the word field values](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Field-codes-in-Word-b0536e6f-5a23-4408-b90f-e7fc24c75416)