# PHPWord - Getting a count of pages?

Tags: php, phpword

I'm using PHPWord's template parser to make a document, then the command line to auto-print the document. The document MUST be on a single page, because it's a certificate, and is to be printed on special paper.

I'm adding in peoples' names, so people with longer names could throw one line onto two, and push everything down onto a second page.

Does PHPWord have a way to count the number of pages, so I can raise an error if the number of pages exceeds one?

Comment: [Google: PHPWord count pages](https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=AocNWNSmIsnDaKLdsqAP#q=phpword+count+pages) First result: [PHPword, get total number of pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143941/phpword-get-total-number-of-pages). Why ask a question that 1) Was asked before 2) Has an answer 3) You could've found yourself faster than creating this question.

Comment: @icecub Because almost a year and a half has passed since that question was asked. The option could have been added in by then. There could also be "hacky" ways to do it. When I searched the docs for a way to replace an image in a template, I found very little, but found the answer by using the zip class to delete and re-add my image. Hacky, but it worked. So I asked this question because I wasn't satisfied with the answer given in the link you posted.

Comment: Instead of doing "hacky" stuff, it might be a better idea to solve your problem at its roots. Check the maximum number of characters that can be printed safely and simply don't allow the user to input more characters. Catch the problem before it occurs by giving an error if to many characters are submitted through the form before even creating a document out of it. Or, search other solutions like perhaps [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: Because the names come from our HR system, user input is already disabled in a sense. PDF might be an option, but I'll have to check with the project manager.

Comment: I **strongly** suggest switching to PDF. I understand Word might be prefered, but this limits you in your options a lot! Word uses lines and perhaps tables. PDF uses coordinates. Meaning you can assign the space for each type of data pixel perfect. It'll give you a huge increase in flexability. You also most likely can't be sure each client has Word, as it's not free. PDF is free! So everyone can download / print it. And that's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Also, if you're hesitating because you think it'll be a lot of work to switch from what you have right now to FPDF, just take a look at how it works. You'll find it extremely easy to use and have the switch done in no time :)

Answer (score 1):

After pawing through the source, it looks like it can't be done yet.

However in app.xml there's a tag called "Pages" that **should** contain the number of pages. I don't think it's accurate, but it's at least something.

Here's some sample code:

```
  // Include PHPWord and other stuff before here
  function getPages() {
    $zip = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive();
    $zip->open("/path/to/your/document.docx");
    preg_match("/\<Pages>(.*)\<\/Pages\>/", $zip->getFromName("docProps/app.xml"), $var);
    return $var[0];
  }
```

This returns `1` for me on a document that should have 2 pages. It could be PHPWord not bothering to calculate the number of pages, or it counting page breaks only, but at least it's a start.

EDIT: Using the Word command line, I can update the page count programatically:

`\path\to\winword.exe /mToolsWordCountRecount /mFileSave /mFileCloseOrExit myfile.docx`

This adds a second or two to generation, but at least now I can accurately detect the number of pages

Comment: The page count is not account, I dont know it counts it but in my end, I've got 18 pages of document but it returns 39

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative (PhpOffice\PHPWord library required).

```
    $zip = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive();
    $zip->open('Path/to/Doc/File');
    $xml = new \DOMDocument();
    $xml->loadXML($zip->getFromName("docProps/app.xml"));

    /* Echoes number of pages according to app.xml */
    echo $xml->getElementsByTagName('Pages')->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i retreived the number of pages in a Word 2007+ document, with PHPWord library.
It counts the number of pages inside a DOCX file, just tested and working.

```
require_once 'libs/phpword/bootstrap.php';//Path to PHPWord library
$zip = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive();
$zip->open('docs/my_document_with_several_pages.docx');//relative path to DOCX file
$xml = new \DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($zip->getFromName("docProps/app.xml"));

// Returns the number of pages according to app.xml
echo $xml->getElementsByTagName('Pages')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```